# jQuery Validation breaking in IE7

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to hunt down an issue in IE7, causing the jquery.validate.js script to break. In IE7, I get two of the same error when I include my validation script:

```
SCRIPT3: Member not found.

jquery.js, line 2699 character 4

SCRIPT3: Member not found.

jquery.js, line 2699 character 4
```

Line 2699 of jquery.js (v1.7.1) is:

```
return ( ret.nodeValue = value + "" );
```

My script is:

```
$("#gform_1").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
     }
});
// First Name
$("#input_1_1").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
});
// Last Name
$("#input_1_2").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
});
// Birth Year
$("#input_1_62").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Birth Month
$("#input_1_63").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Birth Day
$("#input_1_64").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Email
$("#input_1_4").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    email: true
});
// Alternate Email
$("#input_1_60").rules("add", {
    email: true
});
// Home Phone Area Code
$("#input_1_67").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Home Phone Prefix
$("#input_1_68").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Home Phone Suffix
$("#input_1_69").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 4
});
// Cell Phone Area Code
$("#input_1_70").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Cell Phone Prefix
$("#input_1_71").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Cell Phone Suffix
$("#input_1_72").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 4
});
// Address
$("#input_1_10").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
});
// City
$("#input_1_11").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// State
$("#input_1_73").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Zip
$("#input_1_12").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    postal_code: true
});
// Months at residence
$("#input_1_75").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Social Security Number Area Number
$("#input_1_77").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Social Security Number Group Number
$("#input_1_78").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 2
});
// Social Security Number Serial Number
$("#input_1_79").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 4
});
// Drivers License Number
$("#input_1_19").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    drivers_license_number: true
});
// Drivers License State
$("#input_1_76").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Employer
$("#input_1_21").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Months at current employer
$("#input_1_81").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Work Phone Area Code
$("#input_1_84").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Work Phone Prefix
$("#input_1_85").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 3
});
// Work Phone Suffix
$("#input_1_86").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 4
});
// Work Phone Extension
$("#input_1_61").rules("add", {
    digits: true
});
// Date of next paycheck
$("#input_1_52").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    date: true
});
// Date of second next paycheck
$("#input_1_53").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    date: true
});
// Total monthly income
$("#input_1_54").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true
});
// ABA Routing Number
$("#input_1_33").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true
});
// Account Number
$("#input_1_34").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true
});
// Bank Name
$("#input_1_35").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
// Months at bank
$("#input_1_87").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
```

Removing this script fixes the issue. Just removing the `$("#gform_1").validate()` function, the error remains. When I remove all the rules, the error remains. It's only when I remove both that the error goes away.

I believe this error is breaking the validation script.

What's causing this issue?

The live site is http://www.olympicloans.com/apply-now/

Comment: Working fine for me. Try to clear the cache. Let me attach a screenshot.

Comment: Is this actually IE7 or IE10 in IE7 mode? I think this is a known bug

Comment: There is an issue with IE7 involving commas, but that doesn't appear to be the problem in this code

Comment: try putting your code in a try/catch, it appears this is a pretty common bug http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on the validation web site:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/845

Basically, it's IE10 in IE7 compatibility mode. The plugin is setting a "novalidate" attribute with attr(), which fails. But if you edit the validation plug-in and change it to use prop() instead, the error goes away.

This seems to work fine in all the browsers I have access to test on. However, I don't have access to a real copy of IE 7. So, your mileage may vary.